# How do I replace a particular string inside RLDC report column expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, rdlc, reportviewer

I just want to replace a particular text with blank space in RDLC REPORT column's expression.

I want to replace .aspx with "" in every string.

I tried writing

```
=Replace(Fields!AuditsUserActivity.Value, "@"+".aspx", string.Empty)
```

it works for this kinda lines

```
Page Applicants.aspx viewed
```

but not for these kinda lines:

```
Data added in Inspectors.aspx
```

i.e. it removed .aspx from those lines in which .aspx appears in in-between but not for those in which .aspx appears at the end of string.

WHY ?

Comment: You have already posted such question before. Why posted again?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal question was never properly answered before, otherwise I am not insane to post it again, instead of dick measuring answer it